# Method with name: sayHi not found on bean - Using apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am using apache camel to communicate to a remote EJB which is deployed in Weblogic Server 12c. when i invoke remote EJB it throws me the below exception
`org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: sayHi not found on bean: ClusterableRemoteRef(3961905123449960886S:192.168.1.98:[7001,7001,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:weblogic:AdminServer [3961905123449960886S:192.168.1.98:[7001,7001,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:weblogic:AdminServer/394])/394 of type: com.iexceed.study.HelloRemoteEJBImpl_6zix6y_IHelloRemoteEJBImpl_12120_WLStub. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]`

My Came-context.xml file is as below

```
    <bean id="ejb" class="org.apache.camel.component.ejb.EjbComponent"> 
    <property name="properties" ref="jndiProperties" /> 
    </bean> 
    <util:properties id="jndiProperties"> 
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop> 
        <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://IPADDRESS:PORT</prop> 
        <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">weblogic</prop> 
        <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">Weblogic@01</prop> 
    </util:properties> 
    <camelContext id="camelclient" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <template id="template" />

    <endpoint id="camelejb" uri="ejb:EJBRemoteModule-1_0-SNAPSHOTEJBRemoteModule-1_0-SNAPSHOT_jarHelloRemoteEJBImpl_IHelloRemoteEJB?method=sayHi"/>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start_0" />
        <to uri="camelejb" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

and the java client class which i am using is

```
   public void postRequest(){
    try {
        String camelID = "camelejb";
        Exchange exchange = null;
        Message msg = null;
        getCamelContext();
        springCamelContext.start();
        System.out.println("Starting camel context.....");
        getUriMap();
        ProducerTemplate template = springCamelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        System.out.println("camelejb::::::" + getUriMap().get("camelejb"));
        exchange = template.request(getUriMap().get(camelID), new Processor() {

            public void process(Exchange exchng) throws Exception {
               exchng.getIn().setBody("");
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Exception:" + exchange.getException());
        exchange.getException().printStackTrace();
        msg = exchange.getOut();

        System.out.println("Message:" + msg);
        springCamelContext.stop();
        System.out.println("Stopping Camel Context....");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

EJB :

```
    @Remote
    public interface IHelloRemoteEJB {

    public void sayHello(String name);

    public void sayHi();
    }
```

Having no clue why this error is thrown when the method is available in my EJB.
Will be really grateful from heart because i am already in soup.

Comment: I'm resisting the temptation to say: "No soup for you!!". Anyway, to genuinely offer to help, may I ask- is your IHelloRemoteEJB interface exported correctly via OSGI?

Comment: I am not using **OSGI**. Its a simple Maven EJB module and deployed the JAR file in Weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

What's the result of below code?

```
getUriMap().get("camelejb")
```

If you want to reference an endpoint in the camel route, you should do like this

```
<endpoint id="endpoint1" uri="direct:start"/>
<endpoint id="endpoint2" uri="mock:end"/>

<route>
  <from ref="endpoint1"/>
  <to uri="ref:endpoint2"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Endpoint[ejb://EJBRemoteModule-1_0-SNAPSHOTEJBRemoteModule-1_0-SNAPSHOT_jarHelloRemoteEJBImpl_IHelloRemoteEJB?method=sayHi]. Out put of **getUriMap().get("camelejb")**